# Sencha Touch native - Cordova build fails with EACCESS error

Tags: cordova, ant, sencha-touch, cordova-3, sencha-cmd

I've got sencha touch project. Doing sencha "app build native" fails with error at cordova part.

Error can be reproduced calling separately "cordova build":

```
Running command: project/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/build args=[]
execvp(): Permission denied
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
Error: /Users/denisobydennyh/sites/checkdrive/phone-   app/src/main/webapp/cordova/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Previously it was working. Ant is accessible. "build" file has execute flag for all. Project dir has 777 permissions.

Cordova version 3.4
Ant version 1.9.2

What can be the source of error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that path to ant was set as:

~/path/to/bin/ant

After changing to

/full/path/to/bin/ant

The error has gone and build is successful.
Seems that problem was here. But by some magic - some times this configuration was working.

Comment: Hi Denis. Where did you change the path to ant? I'm getting this same issue but one project builds, the other doesn't - so can't be my global path! Thanks

Comment: I can't find at the moment exact file, but I think **/etc/profile** should suit your purposes.